# Importing quandl using python 27

Tags: python, python-2.7, quandl

I'm trying to import quandl and have downloaded it from Github and unzipped it to C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\quandl but whenever I run my file "quandltest.py", I get "ImportError: No module named inflection". I then downloaded inflection from Github and saved it to the site-packages folder but still get the following whenever I run the file. I'm using a Python 27 IDLE to import quandl (I get the same error using Pycharm). Anyone have any idea/the same issue?? Thanks! I also do not have access to my command window as it has been disabled by the admin so I cannot pip install.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Python27/quandltest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import quandl

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\quandl\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .model.database import Database

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\quandl\model\database.py", line 11, in <module>
    from quandl.connection import Connection

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\quandl\connection.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .util import Util

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\quandl\util.py", line 1, in <module>
    from inflection import parameterize

ImportError: No module named inflection
```

Comment: You generally need to install packages to be able to use them. Hopefully, you will just need to run the packages `install.py` script. Please see [Installing Python Modules (Legacy version)](https://docs.python.org/2/install/) in the Python docs.

Comment: I have run the setup.py files of both quandl and inflection (opened them in IDLE and run with no issues). Then when I "import quandl" in the Shell I get a new error:
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import quandl
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\quandl\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .model.merged_dataset import MergedDataset
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\quandl\model\merged_dataset.py", line 1, in <module>
    from more_itertools import unique_everseen
ImportError: No module named more_itertools

Again, download & run setup.py but no luck